# Failed to set unit properties on user-1007.slice: Unit user-1007.slice is not loaded

Tags: centos, cgroups

I'm trying to limit a Linux user via `cgroups`. I used the following command:

```
systemctl set-property user-1007.slice CPUQuota=50%
```

The number `1007` is the user id I want to limit.

But after executing that, I get the following message:

> ```
> Failed to set unit properties on user-1007.slice: Unit user-1007.slice
> is not loaded.
> ```

I tried searching the interwebs, but could not find anything.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

- CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Comment: Your question needs to explain why you thought that it _was_ loaded, and why you picked the number 1007.

Comment: That's the user id `1007`. Why I thought it was loaded? I didn't think I had to load anything? I'm fairly new too cgroups.

Answer (score 0):

User with id 1007 not logged in. First login as that user then set limits

> systemctl set-property user-1007.slice CPUQuota=50%

You can use this command to list all active slice or append --all to list all

> systemctl list-units --type=slice

See this thread for more info http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1540450

Comment: This did not work. I After the first command, I had to input the root password, and even after that, I got the same error `Failed to set unit properties on user-1007.slice: Unit user-1007.slice is not loaded.`.

Comment: In one terminal login as 1007. In another terminal run this 'systemd-cgtop' and see whether the 1007 slice is loaded. Then run 'systemctl set-property user-1007.slice CPUQuota=50%'.